# Unable to Install searchable 0.6.5 for grails 2.2.3

Tags: grails, searchable-plugin

When I need searchable 0.6.5 plugin for grails 2.2.3, I modifed BuildConfigh.groovy as following:

```
dependencies {

compile ":searchable:0.6.5"
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"
    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"}
    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    compile ":searchable:0.6.5"
}
```

After saving the file, I refresh dependency in order to install the plugin, but I got the message below:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.3
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: searchable-0.6.5.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_5/searchable-0.6.5.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'
| Downloading: searchable-0.6.5.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_5/searchable-0.6.5.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

| Downloading: searchable-0.6.5.pom.sha1
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_5/searchable-0.6.5.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- :searchable:0.6.5

Process was killed
```

I thought it could be my internet problem, but I checked the internet connection is OK. Did you encounter problem like this? Could anyone help me solve install searchable 0.6.5 problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But,the same message appears when I changed to 0.6.4，:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
  grailsCentral: bad organisation found in http://grails.org/plugins/grails-searchable/tags/RELEASE_0_6_4/searchable-0.6.4.pom: expected='' found='org.grails.plugins'

Answer (score 1):

You can't use version 0.6.5 with 2.2.3 - see the notes at the plugin page: http://grails.org/plugin/searchable

Use version 0.6.4. The only difference is a trivial fix to get the plugin working in 2.3.